# CSS-only square div fitting inside rectangle div

Tags: css

I have determined how to set a div height based on its width (using percentage width and padding-bottom).  But I also need to be able to set a div width based on its height.  I have tried using vw/vm/vh units, but those are relative to the viewport and not the container.

So, in the following example

```
<body>
    <div class="rectangle">
        <div class="square">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's some non-working CSS that only works in portrait:

```
.rectangle {
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

.square {
  background-color:blue;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:100%;
}
```

I would like .rectangle to fill its container, meaning as the window size changes, .rectangle may go from a landscape layout to a portrait layout.  When this happens, I want the .square div to fill as far as it can without losing its square shape.

So, if the browser window is wider than it is tall (landscape), the .rectangle should fill the window, and the .square should be as tall as the rectangle is tall, and as wide as the rectangle is tall.

And if the browser window is taller than it is wide (portrait), the .rectangle should fill the window, and the .square should be as wide as the rectangle is wide, and as tall as the rectangle is wide.

So, I can use media queries to swap out styles between landscape and portrait, and I have a solution for the portrait case, but I haven't found a solution to the landscape case.  How do I get the square to fill its parent's height, and limit its width to maintain aspect ratio of a square?

Comment: how bout some css code for a css related question?

Comment: There are different approaches that do not work together.  Since I haven't found a solution yet, my CSS won't be particularly relevant to the solution.

Here are some possibilities for the portrait case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/how-to-maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-using-only-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- Place a replaced element with a 1:1 ratio inside the square.

  For example, it can be a 1px × 1px squared image, or a canvas.

  Style this replaced with `height: 100%`, so that it spans the entire square vertically.

  Let it have the default `width: auto`, so that its width respects the 1:1 aspect ratio.

  Style it with `display: block` to avoid the [extra space below image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5804256/1529630) problem.
- Make the square use the [shrink-to-fit width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) algorithm to calculate its width, so that it will have a 1:1 ratio too.

  You can achieve this by floating it or with `display: inline-block`.
- If you want the square to have contents, place them in an absolutely positioned wrapper in order to prevent them from altering the sizes of the square.

  Make that wrapper as big as the square with `top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0`, and make the square its relative container.

This should work. However, for some reason browsers do not seem to update the width when the window is resized, so it only works initially. Forcing a rerender with JS solves this problem.

```js
var s = document.getElementById('square'),
    p = s.parentNode,
    n = s.nextSibling;
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  // Force a rerender
  p.removeChild(s);
  p.insertBefore(s, n);
});
```

```css
html, body, #square, canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
#square {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
#contents {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <canvas height="1" width="1"></canvas>
  <div id="contents">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not having any luck forcing a re-render. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac

Comment: @richremer Uhm, unsetting and resetting some styles altering the styles with devtools seems to work, though. I will try to find a JS way.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what the issue was.  The canvas is square, but has no background-color.  The container wasn't square after resize, and the red threw me.

Comment: OK, I have included this rerendering part. It's ugly, and at this point I could use JS to calculate the width corresponding to the 1:1 ratio, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest done when `.rectangle` literally takes the full window - in other words, its width and height are `100vw` and `100vh` respectively.

If that is the case, then your square is simply:

```
.square {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
    .square {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vw;
    }
}
```

It may be a little trickier to vertically-center the square in the portrait view, but certainly not impossible. `margin-top: calc(50vh - 50vw)` would do it, for instance.

Comment: "I have tried using vw/vm/vh units, but those are relative to the viewport and not the container"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jquery to listen for the resize events. Check out the this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neumann1990/ut1jgnwe/1/).

```js
$(".screen").resizable({});

$(".screen").on("load resize",function(e){
    var rectangle = $(".rectangle");
    var square = $(".square");
    
    var rectWidth = rectangle.width();
    var rectHeight = rectangle.height();
    if(rectWidth < rectHeight){
     square.width(rectWidth);
        square.height(rectWidth);
    }
    else{
     square.width(rectHeight);
        square.height(rectHeight);
    }
});
```

```css
.screen{
    background: gray;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.rectangle{
    background: blue;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
}

.square{
    background: red;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen">
    <div class="rectangle">
        <div class="square">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It includes JQueryUI only to simulate the resizing of the "screen".

Answer (score 0):

If you can use min and the parent is your rect then you could do this:

```
.rectangle {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.square {
  width: min(80vw, 80vh);
  height: min(80vw, 80vh);
}
```