# WebKit SVG height and max-height differences

Tags: html, css, svg, aspect-ratio

If you run the following two examples in Chrome or Safari (Firefox is not affected), you will see the differences on the width of the SVG image.

The first example seems like the correct behavior IMO. But it looks like the svg is being *stretched* in the second example. Is that a bug? Is there any fix?

Example 1 - `height:100%`, it works as expected.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  background: silver;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/mozilla.svg">
```

Example 2 - `max-height:100%`, the main part of the image is shifted to the center, and leaving a large amount of space on the left and right.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  background: silver;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/mozilla.svg">
```

Comment: It seems using `height` affects `width` via intrinsic ratio, and `max-height` doesn't.

Comment: Chrome has not been "webkit" for a couple of years.

Comment: @Rob True, but Blink is still based on WebKit.

Comment: @Oriol Yes but I'm not sure if webkit is actually part of the problem here as mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems certainly a bug. [CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-height) says

> for replaced elements with both [`width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) and [`height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height)
>   computed as `auto`, use the algorithm under [Minimum and maximum
>   widths](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths) above to find the used width and height. Then apply the
>   rules under ["Computing heights and margins"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins) above, using the
>   resulting width and height as if they were the computed values.

In the Minimum and maximum widths algorithm, we have this case:

- Constraint violation: `h > max-height`
- Resolved Width: `max(max-height * w/h, min-width)`
- Resolved Height: `max-height`

Since `min-width` is `0`, the resolved width should be `max-height * w/h`.

Webkit seems to use `w` instead, so it's a bug.

As a workaround, you can use the [common technique to force an aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32425539/1529630).

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* Shrink-to-fit width */
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ratio {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.filler {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: silver;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="ratio" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/mozilla.svg">
  <img class="filler" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/mozilla.svg">
</div>
```

However, note that the effect will only work when you load the page. If then you resize the window, it will break. To fix this, force a rerender with JS:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('wrapper'),
      parent = el.parentNode,
      next = el.nextSibling;
  parent.removeChild(el);
  parent.insertBefore(el, next);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; /* Shrink-to-fit width */
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ratio {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.filler {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: silver;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="ratio" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/mozilla.svg">
  <img class="filler" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/mozilla.svg">
</div>
```